# Check the class of an element with regex

Tags: jquery, regex, find, contains

How with jQuery I can check the class of an element ?

For example, in this code, I want to get the `cl_gry50` class.

```
<span class="rate rate_cl_gry cl_gry50">
  <img src="img.png">
</span>
```

So, sometimes, the class I need to check could be:

- cl_gry10
- cl_gry20
- cl_gry30
- cl_gry40
- cl_gry50

Do I need a regex ?
Thanks.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fethnzLh/

Answer (score 2):

Sterling Archer's answer is good start, here is an improved version:

```
$("span[class*='cl_gry']").filter(function() {
    return this.className.match(/(^|\W)cl_gry/);
});
```

This will use the selector for better performance and for matches it uses regex to filter out the unwanted ones.

Tested with this HTML:

```
<span class="something cl_gry50"></span>
<span class="cl_gry50"></span>
<span class="fake_cl_gry"></span>
```

Will match the first 2 spans, but not the third one.

If you want the string "cl_gry50", you can modify the checker like this:

```
var found = [];
$("span[class*='cl_gry']").filter(function() {
    var match = this.className.match(/((^|\W)cl_gry[^\W]+)/);
    if (!match) return false;
    found.push(match[0]);
    return true;
});
console.log(found); //Will contain ["cl_gry50", "cl_gry50"]
```

You can filter the duplicated ones out using `indexOf`, but that needs polyfill for IE8.

Answer (score 0):

another way to skin this cat

**Sample HTML**

```
<span id='span1' class="rate rate_cl_gry cl_gry50">
</span>

<span id='span2' class="cl_gry50">
</span>

<span id='span3' class="rate rate_cl_gry">
</span>
```

**JS**

```
    $.extend($.expr[":"], {
        cl_gryN: function(e)
        {
            var cl_gryN = false;
            $.each($(e).attr('class').split(" "), function(k, v) {

                if (/cl\_gry[\d]+/.test(v))
                {
                    cl_gryN = true;
                }
            });
            return cl_gryN;
        }
    });

console.log($('#span1').is(':cl_gryN')); //true
console.log($('#span2').is(':cl_gryN')); //true
console.log($('#span3').is(':cl_gryN')); //false
```